# Why permission error with .. in iTerm2 but not with cd ..? Needed permission?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

Why do I receive a permission error when I execute `..` in iTerm2, but `cd ..` works fine?

> zsh: permission denied: ..

What specific permission is needed for this?

Comment: `..` denotes a directory. A directory is not a program. That's the reason for the _permission denied_  message. The closest you can do to avoid the error, is to configure the shell, that naming a directory as if it were a command, would implicitly cd into this directory. However, I don't know whether this is what you want to achieve, because you did not specify in your question, what effect you want to see when using a directory name as a command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set -o autocd` will enable that behaviour. `man zshoptions` says:

> `AUTO_CD` (`-J`) If a command is issued that can't be executed as a normal command, and the command is the name of a directory, perform the `cd` command to that directory. This option is only applicable if the option `SHIN_STDIN` is set, i.e. if commands are being read from standard input. The option is designed for interactive use; it is recommended that `cd` be used explicitly in scripts to avoid ambiguity.